# SQL Server 2014 Bulk insert utf-16 BE missing rows

Tags: sql-server, utf-16

I need to import a utf-8 csv file int sql server 2014

since utf-8 is not supported and the best solution is to us utf-16, I converted the file into utf-16 BE

in Notepad++ the rowterminator is shown as CR LF

and used the following query

```
BULK INSERT [test].[dbo].[csv_test]
FROM 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\16052017.csv'
WITH
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
  ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  ,BATCHSIZE      = 50000
  ,DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'
  ,CODEPAGE       = '1201'
  ,FIRSTROW       = 2
  ,TABLOCK
)
```

That works only partially since seems not recognize "some" terminators and instead importing 51 rows imports only 25, with in latest field the full previous row.

I tried to change both FieldTerminator and RowTerminator into ',\0' and '\n\0' respectively and also in \n\0\r\0'
    but best result is with simple '\n' but as told got only half rows

What I'm doing wrong?

well, sorry it works.. problem was the ID field I added: it was creating all that mess

but since I would use a formatfile that allows me to avoid some rows.. I translated the procedure as follows:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spImportCSV_test
    (
        @FilePath   nvarchar(200)='C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\16052017.csv',
        @FirstRow   nvarchar(5)='2',
        @FMT        nvarchar(20)='csv_test'

    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    Declare @Query nvarchar(max),
            @Tablename nvarchar(100)='test.dbo.csv_test'

    SET @Query = 'BULK INSERT ' 
              + @Tablename 
              + ' FROM ''' 
              + @FilePath 
              + ''' WITH ( FORMATFILE = ''C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\fmt\'+@FMT+'.fmt'', FIRSTROW = '+@FirstRow+')';
        print @Query
        EXEC (@query);

    END
```

where csv_test.fmt is:

```
    12.0
    13
    1       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     1    RegisteredItemN             Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    2       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     2    CountryOfDestination        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    3       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     3    Customer                    Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    4       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     4    Identifier                  Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    5       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     5    Freight                     Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    6       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     6    HAWB                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    7       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     7    MAWB                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    8       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     8    Name                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    9       SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","     9    Address                     Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    10      SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","    10    Postcode                    Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    11      SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","    11    City                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    12      SQLNCHAR             0       500     ","    12    Weight                      Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    13      SQLNCHAR             0       500     "\n"   13    Connote                     Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
```

but I get this error:

```
    Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 1 (RegisteredItemN).

    The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
    Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Comment: Well CRLF is \r\n but it should not cause what you observe, in NPP try view > show symbol > line endings & see what they are.

Comment: what do You mean by " seems not recognize "some" terminators"

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't assume it's a row terminator problem at all. More likely is that you don't have proper text delimiters or something like that which could be causing multiple rows to be read as one. Can you post some of the data? Like, two successful rows and two failed rows?

Comment: Sorry, problem was the ID field I added.. that was creating all that mess :-(

Now I need to "translate" this query using `FORMATFILE`: please look at the question